# Submission of radio button variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, forms

I am writing a program which will display a list students of a class and in front of each student name there are three radio button for Absent, present and on leave.

The list of student is generated with while loop. Now I want to pass the value of radio button through a variable like this.

```
echo "<tr>"
   . "<td>$id</td>"
   . "<td>$name</td>"
   . "<td><input type=radio name=$name value=P></td>"
   . "<td><input type=radio value=L name=$name></td>"
   . "<td><input type=radio name=$name value=A></td>"
   . "</tr>";
```

Is this possible to send value of radio button like this?

Comment: Yes. But name should be same for all three radio buttons and it should not repeat for other records or other radio button group. Keep name like `name='your_name'`. You can also pass the `value` of button using variable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but please do note that your input attributes should have single/double quotes.

```
echo "<input type=radio name='$name' value='p' />";
```

or you can escape double quotations like this

```
echo "<input type=radio name=\"$name\" value=\"P\">";
```

or concatenate php variables

```
echo '<input type=radio name="'.$name.'" value="P">";
```

**UPDATE:**
Checking each student's profile

1. Inside your while loop create an array name. An **array name** is like this, it has **square brackets** after the string 'attendance'.

   ```
   <input name="attendance[]" />
   ```
2. Now, for each student's row. Assign the student ID inside the array name.

   ```
   echo "<tr>"
   . "<td>".$id."</td>"
   . "<td>".$name."</td>"
   . "<td><input type='radio' name='attendance[".$id."]' value='P'></td>"
   . "<td><input type='radio' name='attendance[".$id."]' value='L'></td>"
   . "<td><input type='radio' name='attendance[".$id."]' value='A'></td>"
   . "</tr>";
   ```
3. Putting the $id inside your array name will serve as your pointer, use it in your backend to update each student's attendance status.

   ```
   foreach ($_POST['attendance'] as $key => $value) {
   //$_POST['attendance'] variable is an array.
   //Where $key variable is your Student ID, use this to update their status
   //Where $value is a student's selected attendance status.

     echo 'Student ID:'. $key . ' is '. $value . '<br>';
     //Update a student's attendance status using $key as their id.
   }
   ```

You can also simulate this code I made: http://viper-7.com/Tb1lbo

Comment: thankx... but what shuld be on next page.. $nameOpt=$_POST['$name']; can we write like this?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Assigning PHP variables do not need to have quotations unless it's a string.

Comment: Remove the single quotations on $_POST['$name']. $name is a php variable not a string.

Comment: thanks .. it helped me... but still i have issue regarding receiving my desired P, A, L on the next page so that i can save the attendance on the profile table of each student..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Code:

```php
<?php

$students = [
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Amy'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Bob'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'Charlie'
    ]    
];

echo 
'<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">' .
'<table>' .
'   <thead>' .
'       <tr>' .
'           <th>Student Id</th>' .
'           <th>Student Name</th>' .
'           <th>Attendance (P / L / A)</th>' .
'       </tr>' .
'   </thead>' .
'       <tbody>';

foreach ($students as $student) {
    echo 
    '       <tr>' .
    '           <td>' . $student['id'] . '</td>' .
    '           <td>' . $student['name'] . '</td>' .
    '           <td>' .
    '               <input type="radio" name="attendance_' . $student['id'] . '" value="P" />' .
    '               <input type="radio" name="attendance_' . $student['id'] . '" value="L" />' .
    '               <input type="radio" name="attendance_' . $student['id'] . '" value="A" />' .
    '           </td>' .
    '       </tr>';
}

echo
'       <tr>' .
'           <td colspan="3">' .
'               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Attendance" />' .
'           </td>' .
'       </tr>' .
'   </tbody>' .
'</table>' .
'</form>';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

And on form submit:

```
Array
(
    [attendance_1] => P
    [attendance_2] => L
    [attendance_3] => L
    [submit] => Attendance
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include single or double quotes around the name like this:

```
<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td><input type='radio' name='$name' value='P'></td><td><input type='radio' value='L' name='$name'></td><td><input type='radio' name='$name' value='A'></td></tr>";
```

You can then use the name of the radio button group to get the value from the `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobal depending on your request type.

```
$name = 'name_of_the_radios'
$studentPresence = $_POST[$name] //For get requests use $_GET
if($studentPresence == 'P')
{
    //Student is present
}
else if($studentPresence == 'A')
{
    //Student is absent
}
else if($studentPresence == 'L')
{
    //Student is on leave
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid student presence argument');
}
```

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$id=$row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];
echo <tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td><input type='radio' name='$name' value='P'></td><td><input type='radio' value='L' name='$name'></td><td><input type='radio' name='$name' value='A'></td></tr>";
}
here is my code